# Python mixing inputs with variables

Tags: python, variables, input

I have some variables and in an input I need to specify a variable.

for example if an input is "B1 5" then the Integer B1 gets +5.

I know how to do this the very long way, but my application has many Integer variables which all need to do this.

Comment: Don't use separate variables, put the ones you would like to update at some point in a dict.

Comment: perhaps you're looking for [ast.literal_eval](https://kite.com/python/docs/ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than statically naming your variables in your code, keep them in a dictionary so you can easily address them by name at runtime.

Here's a demo of how this might work:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict

vars: Dict[str, int] = defaultdict(int)
while True:
    try:
        var, inc = input("Gimme a variable and an increment: ").split()
        vars[var] += int(inc)
    except:
        break
print(dict(vars))
```